# Rogue WPAD server attack

Tags: malware, proxy, spoofing

Today I encountered something I have certainly not seen before first hand. Our IDS blocked some outbound traffic attempts from 5 servers with no WAN access. This traffic was leading to an inactive address hosting a nonexistent wpad.dat file. 208.91.197.132/wpad.dat is the address and file.

These devices do not use DHCP, and therefore could not have been accessing a bad record.
DNS that these devices use appears to be unpoisoned.
The only thing left, and what I predict, is that WPAD is relying on NetBIOS broadcast to find a WPAD server, which is then forwarding to the above address.

The IDS blocked attempts starting 2 days ago, about every hour, and the IDS block logs matched up perfectly with outbound WSUS http requests.

There isn't any infection we have definitions for on the affected hosts.

Any ideas? At this point, I believe a device made its way onto the network and WPAD picked it up.

No, we aren't running IE 5.0 :)

Comment: wsus http requests were directed at the correct server.

Answer (score 2):

[WPAD attack](https://www.trustedsec.com/july-2013/wpad-man-in-the-middle-clear-text-passwords/) is a common attack technique among penetration testers (and attackers) usually performed on the network segment where workstations can be found. Doing WPAD attack on servers might make sense, but it is not common. E.g. there can be an auto-update mechanism which downloads regularly something from the internet. But as you said, your servers had no WAN access.

And yes, the most likely scenario is that there was a device on the network which answered to the WPAD requests. In the future follow best practices and both register the WPAD hostname in your local DNS server, and meanwhile disable "Autodetect proxy settings" on client and server machines.